# Background image of control bugged

Tags: c#, image, winforms, transparency

I've done a mini test program to prototype a way to drag and drop an image (at the right)(using a button as a support) to a panel (left part)(The current panel background letter are only for test purpose) and to move it inside the panel perimeter.

[image: image2]

The image on the moving control is manually drawn during the Paint event :

```
    void bouton_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        Button but = sender as Button;

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.triaxe);
        img.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, but.Width, but.Height);
    }
```

As you can see below, during the moving process, the background of the moved control is frezzed. So it is not very pretty

[image]

Is it to make the progress smoother ?

Thank you.

This is the code to move my triaxe on the form :

```
    void bouton_MouseUp( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

        button.Tag = false;
        button.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    void bouton_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if (button.Tag != null && (bool)button.Tag == true)
        {
            button.Left += e.X - MouseDownLocation.X;
            button.Top += e.Y - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }

    private Point MouseDownLocation;

    void bouton_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        button.Tag = true;
        button.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
```

Comment: _using a button as a support_ I think it is more a problem than a support. Why not draw the image itself ? The way you do it you always seem to include the button's last background. Use the paint event of the background control/form instead to draw the original image.

Comment: Hello, using a button instead of directly draw on form allows me to move it

Comment: ?? You can use the same logic without a button, no?

Comment: Drawing the image directly on the canvas form won't me allow me to include some functionnalities : - moving the triaxe easily. - Add the possiblity to display a submenu -delete the image -....

Comment: I hav no idea what you mean by all that. Do show the moving code!

Comment: I've add the moving code

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you do not want to draw the graphics alone but do want a `Control` with transparency move on top of another `Control`.

You have to solve **two** problems:

1. Winforms doesn't support transparency well; you have two options:

   - Either let the system fake it for you
   - Or do the faking yourself.

For the first it is enough to have a control with a transparent backcolor and an Image or BackgroundImage (depending on the control type) with transparency and then **nest** the moving control in the background control.

For a simplistic test you can add `if (button.Parent != panel1) button.Parent = panel1;` to your mousedown code. This will look jumpy but should display transparency correctly. (Don't forget to make the Backcolor transparent; in your code your make it `SystemColors.Control`.

To fake it yourself you would do exactly what the system does:

- You get the target suface in a bitmaps (with `DrawToBitmap`) and then combine the area the mover currently covers with the image; here getting that area is key.
- Then you can set that image as backgroundimage or draw it onto the mover.

---

2. The other problem is with the moving code. Here the issue is that when you move the mouse the `MouseMove` event is triggered and you can move the control. But by moving it the mouse will have moved **relativly** to the new location and **the event will be triggered again** leading to flicker an jumpiness!

To avoid this you can test the numbers **or** use a flag **or** unregister the move event before setting the location and re-register afterwards.

Also setting the location in one go instead of the two coordinates is a good idea..: `button.Location = new Point(button.Left + e.X - MouseDownLocation.X, button.Top + e.Y - MouseDownLocation.Y);`

---

Imo you should still consider drawing just the graphics on On `panel.MouseMove`  and  `panel.Paint`. On `panel.MouseUp` you can still add a `Button` to the `panel.Controls` right there. Both issues are avoided and you are free to add the functionality you want as well..